# testdroid recorder Vs acra

Tags: android, acra

I recently read about testdroid, to track user bugs of my apps, and also I used ACRA that is pretty cool, but I would like to know from users which is better and if is really worthy to pay for testdroid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to say that the code generation one gets from testDroid isn't really enough to justify the price tag.  It works out ok. for saving yourself from writing the test code for button clicks and presses, but for anything more complicated in terms of gestures or dragging (which played prominently into our app), it just didn't seem to work very well.  Granted, this was a few months ago, and they might have improved since then.